# Can someone explain this Swift function to me?

Tags: ios, swift

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

  }
```

This is only my second day of Swift. I've been working through [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1) Apple tutorial.

What I see here is a function that has two parameters. One named picker of type `UIImagePickerController` and the second ... that's where is all falls apart for me.

What is `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]`? It doesn't look like a simple parameter with a type.

And

Comment: Lookup "external parameter names" in the Swift book.

Comment: See also https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

Comment: It's a dictionary with a string key and a value of type AnyObject